# What is the right way to redirect stdio when spawning a process in Rust?

Tags: rust

I see two ways to do it (Rust v0.9).  For the examples below, assume I want to redirect STDOUT to some file.

The first would be to get the file descriptor for the file and then pass it to the `std::run::ProcessOptions` struct.  Here's how `std::run::process_status` does it:

```rust
let mut opt_prog = Process::new(prog, args, ProcessOptions {
    env: None,
    dir: None,
    in_fd:  Some(unsafe { libc::dup(libc::STDIN_FILENO)  }),
    out_fd: Some(unsafe { libc::dup(libc::STDOUT_FILENO) }),
    err_fd: Some(unsafe { libc::dup(libc::STDERR_FILENO) })
});
```

It gets the usual filedescriptors for STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR and sets them.  **But how do I get the file descriptor for some arbitrary File I've opened in Rust?**  I haven't found a way to do that.

The second option is to just use the default ProcessOptions via `ProcessOptions::new()` which opens a pipe to stdin, stdout and stderr and lets you grab them, like so:

```rust
let pgm = "ls";
let args = ~[~"-lh"];

match Process::new(pgm, args, ProcessOptions::new()) {
    None => println("fubar"),
    Some(mut p) => {
        {
            let process = &mut p;
            let rdr = process.output();  // grab STDOUT output
            let out = rdr.read_to_str();
            // write output to your file of choice here
        }
        p.close_input();
        p.close_outputs();
        p.finish();
    }
}
```

I'd prefer to do it the first way, but I suspect the second way is the idiomatic way to do it.

What I don't like about the second option is what if I only want to redirect STDOUT, but not the others?  I now have to call `process.error()` and write that back out to STDERR, which seems silly.  I'd also have to do something similar for STDIN, as that has been wrapped in a pipe as well.

Ideas on the best way to this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`std::os::unix::AsRawFd`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/trait.AsRawFd.html) trait, which extends the platform-independent [`std::io::fs::File`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fs/struct.File.html) with the [`as_raw_fd`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/trait.AsRawFd.html#tymethod.as_raw_fd) method to return a file descriptor.

One convenient way to use this and other Unix-specific extensions is to import the [`std::os::unix::prelude`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/prelude/) module. In particular, the example I wrote to originally answer the question is practically the same as the [example](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/index.html) in the documentation now:

```rust
#![feature(globs)]

use std::io::fs::File;
use std::os::unix::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let p = Path::new("/etc/passwd");
    let f = File::open(&p).unwrap();
    let fd = f.as_raw_fd();
    println!("{} fd: {}", p.as_str().unwrap(), fd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely put me on the right track for getting the file descriptor. Your code isn't exactly correct, bcs file::open results `Result<FileDesc, IoError>` (in Rust v0.9 at least), so you have to match/"unwrap" the result to get to the `FileDesc` which has the `fd()` function.

Comment: Also your std::io imports aren't correct - should be `use std::io::{Open, Read}`, at least for v0.9 that I'm using.

Comment: Fixed based on your comments.

Comment: What does it looks like in the nightly? I can't find `native` in the docs there.

Comment: Import the (experimental) [`std::os::unix::prelude`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/prelude/index.html) module, which extends files with Unix-specific operations, namely obtaining the file descriptor (with the `AsRawFd` trait). I'll update the code.